# Error in Paging in gqgrid with local array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, pagination, jqgrid-asp.net

I am facing problem with pagination in jqgrid with array data having 13 records, but the records are not displaying in pages.

How to implement pagination instead of scrolling?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#Table1").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['Inv No', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
                { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150,}
            ],
            rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: '#Div1',
            multiselect: true,
            caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
        });
        var mydata = [
                { id: "1", name: "test1", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "2", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "3", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "4", name: "test1", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "5", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "6", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "7", name: "test1", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "8", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "9", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "10", name: "test1", note: "note", amount: "500.00", tax: "10.00", total: "310.00" },
                { id: "11", name: "test1", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "12", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "13", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
        ];
        for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
            jQuery("#Table1").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
    });
</script>
```

---

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"></asp:Table>
    <div id="Div1"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: already tried: not working!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fill jqGrid in a wrong way. The method `addRowData` is very old. It's low-level method which allows to add row manually. Starting with version 3.7 (the current version is 4.6.0) jqGrid supports local data, local paging, sorting and filtering. To have advantage of the local data you should use *data* parameter of jqGrid. It allows you to save locally in jqGrid all data (more as one can display on one page), but fill in the table only the first page. The code will be about the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mydata = [
            { id: "1", name: "test1", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "2", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "3", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "4", name: "test1", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "5", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "6", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "7", name: "test1", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "8", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "9", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
            { id: "10", name: "test1", note: "note", amount: "500.00", tax: "10.00", total: "310.00" },
            { id: "11", name: "test1", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
            { id: "12", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
            { id: "13", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
        ];

    $("#Table1").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        height: "auto",
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int", key: true },
            { name: 'name', width: 100 },
            { name: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
            { name: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
            { name: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
            { name: 'note', width: 150 }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#Div1',
        multiselect: true,
        caption: "Manipulating Array Data",
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true
    });
});
```

I added in the above code `data: mydata, gridview: true, autoencode: true` parameters, replaced `height: 250` to `height: "auto"`, removed `index` property from all items of `colModel` and added `key: true` to the column which contains unique values which I want to use as rowid.

I understand why you made the code. [The official demo page](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) contains very old code. For example the demo from "Loading Data"\"Array Data" contains the same problems like in your code. By the way the code contains even small bug: it uses `i <= mydata.length` in the loop instead of `i < mydata.length`. I asked Tony (the developer of jqGrid) to update the demo page, but he didn't found the time for it. :-(

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user3166111.htm) uses the above code and it works as expected.

Comment: @user3166111: I'm sure that you made an error in reproducing of the test. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user3166111.htm) which do work.

Comment: @user3166111: Do you opened [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user3166111.htm)? Is it work in your web browser? You can use click on right mouse button and choose "View page source" of context menu to see the code of the demo. You should *exact* compere your code with my code. Additionally you can run the code in debugger (press F12 to start it). You will see the line of your code where you get an error. It helps you to find the error in your code.

Comment: didnt checked for that!!!  I used the sourse ceod thats working, I will make changes in the data only!!!